# How to make gif/svg image start playing using FFImageLoading / Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, svg

I'm being abble to show svg on screen using FFImageLoading but it's freezed(it's a loading spinner). Is there any method to make it play or I have to make the animation by my own?

Comment: I have marked your question to be closed, because you are looking for a tutorial or off-site how to. If you are looking for a solution to a specific problem, you will have to narrow down your question and describe what you have attempted to do yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG's in FFImageLoading are just rendered using Skia, so they wont be animated. Gifs and WebP images, however, should be animated.

You can animate vector drawables on Android using [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable). On iOS you could use something like [PocketSVG](https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG) to load the SVG data as a bezier path and animate that.

The easiest way to animate SVG's would probably be by using [Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/).